# How to get total viewers online on twitch?

Tags: json, api

I don't have any knowledge in dealing with json requests and I'm only used to making http requests inside a game script to get data through api from various websites.

I have read a [tutorial](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/streams#get-stream-by-user) on Twitch on how to make api requests, but I couldn't understand the process.

I have a dedicated server on which I could host a php file as an intermediary to get a direct api response from, I need help on how to make and set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question you just deleted ... which looks like it relates to this question as well.

The page is actually calling the Twitch API if you open up the network tab on your console you will see the call.

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/battlezone_samp?client_id=8bmp6j83z5w4mepq0dn0q1a7g186azi`

This returns a JSON object that you can parse and get the `viewers`

to do this in php

```
$feed = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/battlezone_samp?client_id=8bmp6j83z5w4mepq0dn0q1a7g186azi');
$json = json_decode($feed, true);

echo $json['stream']['viewers'];
```